# Exporting Python Module With Same Name as Package, with srv/msg

Tags: ros, python, setup.py, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT**: MWE can be found [here](https://github.com/tfurf/rospy-srv-module-test).

Per [[1]](http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide) and [[2]](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html), I'm trying to export a python module that is the same name as the package:

```
packagename
 CMakeLists.txt
 package.xml               # catkin_python_setup()
 setup.py                  # generate_distutils_setup( ..., packages=['packagename'], ... )
 |- src/
    |- application.py         # import packagename
    |- packagename/
      |- __init__.py
      |- stuff.py
      |- ...
```

This works as expected, no problem. However, if I introduce a service message and try to import it:

```
packagename
 CMakeLists.txt
 package.xml
 setup.py
 |- srv/
    |- MySrv.srv
 |- src/
    |- application.py         # import packagename
    |- packagename/
      |- __init__.py
      |- stuff.py
      |- use_my_service.py  # from packagename.srv import MySrv
      |- ...
```

At runtime I get

```
ImportError: No module named srv
```

It works if I change the name of the exported module:

```
packagename
 CMakeLists.txt
 package.xml
 setup.py                  # generate_distutils_setup( ..., packages=['notpackagename'], ... )
 |- srv/
    |- MySrv.srv
 |- src/
    |- application.py         # import notpackagename
    |- notpackagename/
      |- __init__.py
      |- stuff.py
      |- use_my_service.py # from notpackagename.srv import MySrv
      |- ...
```

The path in both cases is exactly the same, including

```
$WORKSPACE_ROOT/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

And in both cases I can locate the appropriate `pacakgename/srv/_MySrv.py`. In the working case, the output directory structure looks like:

```
devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
|- notpackagename
  |- __init__.py     # Non-empty, dist-utils generated
|- packagename
  |- __init__.py     # Empty.
  |- srv/
    |- __init__.py 
    |- _MySrv.py
```

And in the non-working case:

```
devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
|- packagename
  |- __init__.py     # Non-empty, dist-utils generated.
  |- srv/
    |- __init__.py 
    |- _MySrv.py
```

It appears that the generated `__init__.py` for the exported module clobbers the knowledge of the existence of submodules, but I'm not sure, I'm not particularly familiar with how catkin does it's magic for this.

Is my expectation for this to work misguided? If it's not supposed to/going to work, what is the preferred method? To prefix the module with `lib`, as in [[3]](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/tree/indigo-devel) ?

- [1] http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide
- [2] http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
- [3] https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/tree/indigo-devel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190244/exporting-python-module-with-same-name-as-package,-with-srv/msg/) by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-14**:
What exact command are you invoking when you get the ImportError? Do you invoke src/application.py as a script / node?

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2014-08-18**:\

> What exact command are you invoking when you get the `ImportError`?

The exception is raised right at import-time, in `use_my_service.py` (part of the module). The specific line looks like `from packagename.srv import MySrv`.

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2014-08-18**:\

> Do you invoke src/application.py as a script / node?

The `src/application.py` is called as a node, via `roslaunch`, with a simple `.launch` file.

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2014-08-18**:
See https://github.com/tfurf/rospy-srv-module-test/ for both working and non-working versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Placing your node under `src/application.py` will interfere with the package resolution of Python. When you import anything from `packagename` it will resolve the relative subfolder rather then the folder in devel space which actually provides your generated message files.

If you stick to the recommendation from the tutorials to place your node scripts in either a `nodes` or `scripts` folder (instead of into `src`) the problem should disappear.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thanks for the hint. This wasn't clear to me after reading http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide#Package.2BAC8-Module_Names_.28__init__.py_files.29 .